# Which is an analogous of QGraphicsScene in QML?

Tags: qt, graphics, qml, qgraphicsscene

I'm a developer who has dabbled with QT and created apps using QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsSceneItem descendants. I'd like to learn me some QML and adapt my app to this framework.

My question is: which is the best QML component for a QGraphicsScene emulation? With this I mean a component that allows for:

- Inserting and positioning thousands *interactive* graphic objects with a reasonable performance
- Zooming, panning and rotating the resulting drawing

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: These two concepts are quite similar. In an approximate comparison `QQuickWindow` is an analog of `QGraphicsScene` and `QQuickItem` is an analog of `QGraphicsSceneItem`. The scene graph is managed and rendered by the `QQuickWindow` class and custom Item types can add their graphical primitives into the scene. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html) you can find more info about QtQuick scene graph.

Comment: I would say Qt3d Scene2D and Scene3D but myself stumbled upon interacting with Qt3d ObjectPicker type while doing overlaps of shapes in the scene. Other than that I managed to achieve really high performance with custom user Geometry for our very specific 3D rendering app.